# update json file from php file after POST Request Angular

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am using the Twitter 1.1 API and displaying a feed of tweets.
Angular makes a `GET` request to a php file `get_tweets.php` which then writes to a json file with all the data, which angular then gets the data from.

The reason for the json file is to cache the results from twitter to ensure that api limits are not exceeded. for this reason I call the twitter API every 10 mins and then update the json file.

I am trying to remove a specific tweet if a user clicks on delete on the front end. What I believe should happen is that a `POST` request is made to the php file which would then delete that specific tweet from the json file.

**FACTORY METHODS USED IN CONTROLLER**

```
....updateTwitter: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'get_tweets.php',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        },
        fetchTwitter: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'twitter_result.json',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }.....
```

**CONTROLLER GET REQUEST TO GET TWEETS & POST REQUEST TO REMOVE TWEET**

```
socialMedia.updateTwitter()
    .then(function(){
        socialMedia.fetchTwitter()
        .then(function(response){
            twitterCtrl.loading = false;
            var result = JSON.parse(response.data.twitter_result);
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
                result[i].created_at = new Date(result[i].created_at);
                twitterCtrl.twitterPosts.push(result[i]);
            }      
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            twitterCtrl.loading = false;
            twitterCtrl.error = true;
        });
    });

this.removeTweet = function(index) {
        var data = JSON.stringify({data: this.twitterPosts.splice(index, 1)});
        $http.post("get_tweets.php", data).success(function(data, status) {
            console.log(data)
        })
    }
```

The code above is logging `data` correctly eg. `data:[{created_at: "2016-05-30T12:28:00.000Z", id: 737259264381726700, id_str: "737259264381726720",…}]`

My question is how can I then remove this tweet from the json file, through the php file. even if it is just removed for 10 minutes until the next GET request is made from the php file to Twitter that is ok.

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php
require_once('twitter_proxy.php');
// Twitter OAuth Config options
$oauth_access_token = '*****';
$oauth_access_token_secret = '*****';
$consumer_key = '*****';
$consumer_secret = '*****';
$user_id = '*****';
$screen_name = 'StackOverflow';
$count = 5;
$twitter_url = 'statuses/user_timeline.json';
$twitter_url .= '?user_id=' . $user_id;
$twitter_url .= '&screen_name=' . $screen_name;
$twitter_url .= '&count=' . $count;
// Create a Twitter Proxy object from our twitter_proxy.php class
$twitter_proxy = new TwitterProxy(
    $oauth_access_token,            // 'Access token' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $oauth_access_token_secret,     // 'Access token secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_key,                  // 'API key' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $consumer_secret,               // 'API secret' on https://apps.twitter.com
    $user_id,                       // User id (http://gettwitterid.com/)
    $screen_name,                   // Twitter handle
    $count                          // The number of tweets to pull out
);

function checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url) {
    $tweets = $twitter_proxy->get($twitter_url);
    $data = array ('twitter_result' => $tweets, 'timestamp' => time());
    file_put_contents('twitter_result.json', json_encode($data));
}

//check if the file exists
if(!file_exists('twitter_result.json')) {
    //Invoke the get method to retrieve results via a cURL request
    //and create a file with timestamp containing tweets
    checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);

}else {
    //if file exists check it has not been updated in 10 minutes
    //if not update the tweets and timestamp
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('twitter_result.json'));
    if ($data->{"timestamp"} > (time() - 10 * 60)) {
        checkForUpdates($twitter_proxy, $twitter_url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use database to store the data? Just send tweet ID and use a soft delete

Comment: @charlietfl i know, i should have taken that approach, but its prob a bit late now. is there a way of doing it the way i am suggesting?

Comment: Why is it too late now? You are basically trying to create a file based database of your own. Wouldn't take very long to convert what you alredy have to use real database